# Counting the occurrences of a command in history

Tags: command-history

I want to count the number of times a command, let's say `man`, occurs within the history.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the U&L stack exchange site! Please review the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to get information on how to best post to this site. To get to your question, [please edit your post to include additional context](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/509481/edit). What have you tried and what is not working? Thank you!

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: Related: [In UNIX, how to find the most commonly used commands in history of unix?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/15021)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the current `history`

```
$ history | grep -cw man
```

and even count all your commands:

```
$ history | awk '{c[$2]++}END{for (x in c) print c[x],x | "sort -n"}'
...
9 grep
9 ssh
10 ping
17 mv
19 mkdir
21 svn
35 perl
43 cd
46 python3
71 ls
96 vi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bash, the history for the current user is located in the file `~/.bash_history`, in case of zsh its `~/.zsh_history`.

Now you can use a simple `grep -cw man ~/.bash_history` to get the number of lines containing the word `man`.

Please note, that whenever a command was used multiple times in line, it only appears once in the history files.